# Convert Image Name stored in MySql Database to Drawable in Android

Tags: android, mysql, drawable

I have this block of code. My Image name is stored in MySql db and now i want to convert it into drawable for Banner Slider Purposes.

"photo" field is image field in database and "about" is image name stored in drawable folder but i want pictures from database in R.drawable."images_stored_in_db".

```
for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = object.getString("name");
    String email = object.getString("email");
    String pass = object.getString("password");
    String photo = Connection.API + object.get("photo");


    banners.add(new DrawableBanner(R.drawable.about));


    ShowItem item = new ShowItem(name,email,pass,photo);
    RegisterContent.ITEMS.add(item);
}
```

Comment: you want to `android get drawable by name` google search query

Comment: why u need drwable only? you can set image as from path

Answer (score 0):

If you have your image name this means that the image exists somewhere on the device - right?
If this is the case.

```
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
String name = object.getString("name");
String email = object.getString("email");
String pass = object.getString("password");
String photo = Connection.API + object.get("photo");

File image = new  File(photo);

//check if the image really exsist
if(image.exists()){

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());

    //.... now do whatever you want to do with it
    //you can use setImageBitmap(bm); to display the image on an ImageView 
}
```